# WPF datagrid does not allow user to add blank rows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I've bound my `DataGrid` to `<ObservableCollection> People`. It generates the columns as expected. My problem is that I want to let the user add blank rows. How can I do that?

Here is my complete code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding People}" 
                  CanUserAddRows="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        Firstname = firstName;
        Lastname = lastName;
    }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        new Person("Jack", "Shephard"),
        new Person("John", "Locke")
    };
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set
        {
            people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("People");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: If [`CanUserAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to true (default value) then user should be able to add new rows already but it needs paramterless constructor. Or add empty `Person` to `ObservableCollection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a standard constructor for the observable class (you can make a class wrapper if you need to differentiate it)

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
```

Comment: Thanks Machine Learning, this the solution!